# comparing date time values in a pandas DataFrame with a specific data_time value and returning the closet one

Tags: python, pandas

I have a date column in a pandas DataFrame as follows:

```
index   date_time
1       2013-01-23
2       2014-01-23
3       2015-8-14
4       2015-10-23
5       2016-10-28
```

I want to compare the values in `date_time column` with a specific date, for example `date_x = 2015-9-14` ad return a date that is before this date and it is the most closet, which is `2015-8-14.`

I thought about `converting the values in date_time column to a list` and then  `compare them with the specific date`. However, I do not think it is an efficient solution.

Any solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way using `searchsorted`, and all my method is assuming the data already order , if not doing the `df=df.sort_values('date_time')`

```
df.date_time=pd.to_datetime(df.date_time)
date_x = '2015-9-14'
idx=np.searchsorted(df.date_time,pd.to_datetime(date_x))
df.date_time.iloc[idx-1]
Out[408]: 
2   2015-08-14
Name: date_time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Or we can do

```
s=df.date_time-pd.to_datetime(date_x)
df.loc[[s[s.dt.days<0].index[-1]]]
Out[417]: 
   index  date_time
2      3 2015-08-14
```

Comment: @Mary yw:-) happy coding

Comment: @Mary btw if this work , would you like accept it ?